# Animation in WPF query

Tags: wpf, animation

I'm playing with WPF for the first time in an animation/graphics context, and I am wondering how you'd move sprites around. I googled and came up with [this](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/Framework/79_The_Padding_Ball_game_in_WPF.aspx) example, but the animation is done by increasing/decreasing the margins and padding.

My question is, is this normal? I would have thought you'd do animation by changing the x and y co-ordinates of a sprite, not its padding.

Answer (score 1):

Position and Margin are the same thing. Position is the distance to the edge of the screen, or the egde of the window. Margin is the same thing.